# How do I start unit testing in Angular 4?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I'm currently following this guide on unit testing .[Unit testing in Angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html)

I went to the "Test environment setup files" and there is a link to a page that should explain how to configure and bootstrap files for unit testing but I get a 404 when I click on it. Also, on the same page it says :"The deep details of these files and how to reconfigure them for your needs is a topic beyond the scope of this guide ." So where can I find details about how to setup files for unit testing? I've tried using the sample files they had but I'm not sure how to tailor them to my needs.

Comment: As a docs member of the team. Could you please fill a bug at angular/angular with the problems you found? Would be good if we can fix the issues.

Comment: https://psamsotha.github.io/angular/2016/12/16/angular2-testing-karma-systemjs.html

Comment: It's working now: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#setup-files

Answer (score 2):

If you use angular-cli, karma and protractor are setup already for unit and e2e testing. It is very easy to create a new project with angular-cli and start unit test (no setup required).